# matlab group list of strings by delimiter

Tags: string, matlab, cell, grouping, delimiter

I have a cell of strings.  Each element is actually a filename that has delimeters according to different categories.  For example, blahblah.speaker.4.id.55  and so on.   I want to be able to group the cell of strings according to one of the delimited values.  For example, I'd like to group the cell by the speaker number.   So I would like to end up with a new cell array where each element of the array contains a cell of the filenames that have the same speaker.

So for example:
element 1: 'blah.speaker.4.doobie', 'blah.speaker.4.dada'  element 2: 'blah.speaker.5.derder' , 'blahblah.speaker5.dodo'

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use a cell, use a [`structure`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html)

Comment: to clarify, i used a struct to get all the files names initially, but I need to group these filenames according to the speaker deliminter. there may be multipel files with the same speaker.  so i created a cell of the filenames using names = {filestruct{:}.name};

Answer (score 0):

As @Adriaan has said, it is best to use a `struct` for storing this type of data. You can then use these structs to group it later. The following code assumes that you have consistent number of parts in all filenames.

```
names = {'blahblah.speaker.4.id.55', ...
         'blahblah.speaker.4.id.66', ...
         'blah.listener.3.id.77'};

output = regexp(names, '\.', 'split');
output = cat(1, output{:});

% Fieldnames for each of the "parts"
names = {'blah_part', 'attendee_type', 'some_number', 'id', 'id_number'};

% Now convert it to a struct
data = cell2struct(output.', names);

3x1 struct array with fields:

    blah_part
    attendee_type
    some_number
    id
    id_number
```

Now let's just convert that id_number to an actual number real quick.

```
id_numbers = num2cell(str2double({data.id_number}));
[data.id_number] = deal(id_numbers{:});
```

Now we can perform actions on this.

Find all cases  where the first part is "blahblah"

```
inds = strcmp({data.blah_part}, 'blahblah');
data_with_blahblah = data(inds);

    2x1 struct array with fields:

        blah_part
        attendee_type
        some_number
        id
        id_number
```

You can do this for any of the fields. If your fields contain numbers (all of your are currently strings). You can do something like.

```
sub_data = data([data.id_number] == 55);

           blah_part: 'blahblah'
       attendee_type: 'speaker'
         some_number: '4'
                  id: 'id'
           id_number: 55
```

If you're not averse to [regular expressions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html), you can also create the `structure` that way.

```
data = regexp(names, '(?<blah_part>.*?)\.(?<attendee_type>.*?)\.(?<some_number>\d*)\.(?<id>.*?)\.(?<id_number>\d*)', 'names')
```